# Swift: listBlobsSegmentedWithContinuationToken method generates errors in Swift sample

Tags: swift, azure

I got this code from this github: [azure-storage-ios/BlobSample/](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios/tree/master/BlobSample)
I am able to create my container and add blobs to it. I verified they are there in the azure portal. I am using the SAS token method per this:

```
var containerURL = "https://<mystorage>.blob.core.windows.net/profiles?se=2016-09-05T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=rw&sv=2015-02-21&sr=c&sig=<mysig>"
var usingSAS = true
self.container = AZSCloudBlobContainer(url: NSURL(string: containerURL)!, error: &error)
// ... later:
blob.uploadFromText(textTextField.text ?? "",  completionHandler: { (error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

But now, I am trying to load blob but receive one or more errors!

```
func reloadBlobList() {
    self.container.listBlobsSegmentedWithContinuationToken(nil, prefix: nil, useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: AZSBlobListingDetails.All, maxResults: 50) { (error : NSError?, results : AZSBlobResultSegment?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("error code! \(error.code)")
            print("error description! \(error.description)")
        }
```

I get this error about AuthorizationPermissionMismatch mainly

> error code! 3
>   error description! Error Domain=com.Microsoft.AzureStorage.ErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Code=AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, AdditionalErrorDetails={
>   }, rawErrorData={length = 279, capacity = 279, bytes = 0xefbbbf3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e ... 3c2f4572726f723e}, OperationContext=, RequestResult=, HTTP Status Code=403, URLResponse= { URL: https://.blob.core.windows.net/profiles?sig=&api-version=2015-04-05&sp=rw&se=2016-09-05T00%3A00%3A00Z&sv=2015-02-21&sr=c&restype=container&comp=list&maxresults=50&include=snapshots,metadata,uncommittedblobs,copy } { status code: 403, headers {
>       "Content-Length" = 279;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
>       Date = "Fri, 27 May 2016 08:12:19 GMT";
>       Server = "Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0";
>       "x-ms-request-id" = "90746e2f-0001-0114-7eef-b7be1e000000";
>       "x-ms-version" = "2015-04-05";
>   } }, Message=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
>   RequestId:90746e2f-0001-0114-7eef-b

the key I generated earlier had the r/w permission and I was able to post blobs to the container, what else should I've done for the retrieval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var containerURL =
>   "https://.blob.core.windows.net/profiles?se=2016-09-05T00%3A00%3A00Z&**sp=rw**&sv=2015-02-21&sr=c&sig="

In order to list blobs in a blob container, you need `List (l)` permission in your SAS. Currently you only have `Read (r)` and `Write (w)` permission. Can you try by creating a new SAS with `List` permission as well?